# how to empty all variables in a long for loop to avoid the program to run out of memory?

Tags: java, loops, memory, for-loop, crash

I have a `for` loop that runs 20.000 times with a `for` loop inside it that runs 20.000 times as well which adds up to a total of 400 million.

in the for loop it adds 20.000 numbers to a string and then writes this string into a txt file. after the writing the string is being set empty like this :`String Name = ""`;

so i will get a total of 20.000 text files with each 20.000 numbers in it.

now if the for loop has created about 200 files it starts to run out of memory and crashes eventually.

how can i avoid this?

-- here is the code --

```
public static void mapScanner()
{

    String content = "";

    for(int z = -10000; z < 10000; z++)
    {
        Util.CreateFile(z);
        for(int x = -10000; x < 10000; x++)
        {
            Block block = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world").getBlockAt(x, Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world").getHighestBlockYAt(x, z) -1, z);

            if(block.getType() != Material.AIR)
            {
                content += Blocks.blockID(block.getType());
            }
        }

        try 
        {
            File file = new File("plugins/Map/" + z + ".txt");
            System.out.println(content);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();
            content = "";

            System.out.println("The file : " + z + ".txt has been created and written.");

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

---

`block.getType()` just returns a number.

---

General code :

```
for(int x = 0; x < 20000; x++)
    {
        String content = "";
        CreateFile(x);
        for(int z = 0; z < 20000; z++)
        {

            content += "1";

        }

        try 
        {
            File file = new File("Map/" + x + ".txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            //System.out.println("The file : " + x + ".txt has been created and written.");

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

---

```
public static void CreateFile(int z) {

    File file = new File("Map/" + z + ".txt");
    boolean fileCreated = false;
    try {
        fileCreated = file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //System.out.println("Error while creating empty file: " + ioe);
    }

    if (fileCreated) {
        //System.out.println("Created empty file: " + file.getPath());
    } else {
        //System.out.println("Failed to create empty file: " + file.getPath());
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be *much* easier to help you if you'd show us the code rather than just describing it. For example, if you're using repeated string concatenation, then just using `StringBuilder` may well be enough to reduce GC churn significantly. But it sounds like it should already be okay, in that everything should be eligible for collection. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would make it *much* easier to help you.

Comment: what is `Util.CreateFile` ?

Comment: this just create's the txt file with the name equal to the number of where the for loop is at that point. also it automaticly checks wether this succeeded or not

Comment: @NielsPeeren honestly, unless one of the bukkit methods stores some state, or the `Util.CreateFile` holds references to files or something, it doesn't look like you should get any memory leaks

Comment: @NielsPeeren is it possible that at the 200th file there happens to just be data that has really big numbers? Or is this happening using lots of different data always at the same place?

Comment: the numbers block.getType() never change these will always be between 0 and 9 so there is never a bigger number then those. also it is not exactly the 200th file it is around the 200th that is where it runs out of memory

Comment: @NielsPeeren I'm suspect of interning strings now(not that I know much about it, I'm just out of other ideas). Instead of defining `String content = "";` at the top, try putting it just above the inner for loop, and remove the `content = "";` line

Comment: You can also try using a StringBuilder for `content` instead of String concatenation.

Comment: so instead of content += Blocks.blockID(block.getType()); what would that be?

Comment: @NielsPeeren same thing. That's still in scope

Comment: @NielsPeeren can you recreate this problem using pure java and post that code? As it stands I can't test your code, and there's still a chance that the out of memory is happening in bukkit itself(in which case this question is more suited for a bukkit forum than here).

Comment: i have tried what you sayd about defining     String content  above the inner loop and removing the     content = "";  but still after 200 files the memory usage is at 5GB and counting

Comment: trying it in a seperate java project without the bukkit now

Comment: i tested in in a different project now and it is currently at 500 files and the RAM usages stays the same

Comment: oh right now it is at 1000 files and the ram usage has doubled so there is still something that keeps using more RAM

Comment: @NielsPeeren can you post that code? That's more general. But it did finish right?

Comment: @Cruncher i added the code without the bukkit stuff in the main post

Answer (score 2):

You will always have performance problems if you keep all contents in memory, show me some code to help you.

One way to me to do this, it's write directly to the file so no need to keep the string in memory.

> > Sorry for my grammar anyway, I'm not great at writing...

Try something like this instead:

```
public static void mapScanner()
{

String content = "";

for(int z = -10000; z < 10000; z++)
{
    File file = new File("plugins/Map/" + z + ".txt");
    // if file doesn't exists, then create it, this inside another try.
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(file);
    OutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(fw);

    for(int x = -10000; x < 10000; x++)
    {
        Block block = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world").getBlockAt(x, Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world").getHighestBlockYAt(x, z) -1, z);

        if(block.getType() != Material.AIR)
        {
            string temp = Blocks.blockID(block.getType());
            System.out.println(temp);
            bw.write(temp.getBytes());
        }
    }

    try 
    {
        // Close all
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
        file.close();
        System.out.println("The file : " + z + ".txt has been created and written.");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: well i am storing the values in a string because it does not have all the values at the start of the for loop but gets the values within. if it has all the values stored in the string it writes it. this is because else i would have to use 400 million writes

Comment: @NielsPeeren - You are using a buffered writer, so that doesn't matter.  Those writes are actually just appends to a buffer

Comment: so there is actually no difference between writing every single number in the same file 20.000 times or writing 20.000 number at once?

Comment: @NielsPeeren - you're rigth but thats what he wants but store them in memory its totaly diferent

Comment: @Niels Peeren - If those classes dont exists in java version your using let me know.

Comment: it does work but it works just as fast as the previous one and it is still using 4gb ram at 100 files created

Comment: i don't know if it is of any use but it generates about 10 to 20 files in just 1 or 2 seconds and then it takes a 10 second break before it does that again , at least that is how the console shows it

Comment: right now it is at about 200 files and it is using 90% of my RAM and 98% of my CPU

Comment: @NielsPeeren Add close to file and stream also, that will decrease use of resources. What your doing is some kind of IO test?

Comment: @NielsPeeren Its a heavy task but dont worry Ive seen process that takes weeks to finish and theres no easy solution.

Comment: @mijail i am trying to scan a world of 20000X20000 blocks and convert it into a top view map in a browser

Comment: @NielsPeeren In java also print alot of info to console is very slow. try also removing all the prints and test again.

Answer (score 1):

replace `String content = ""` with `StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder()` and `content += Blocks.blockID(block.getType())` with `content.append(Blocks.blockID(block.getType()))`

this should make your loop run quite a lot faster. i doubt it will help with your OutOfMemory problem, though.